# Informatica Filter Transformation condition is TRUE without any fileds

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have one mapping with a Filter transformation. This filter transformation has Condition set to `TRUE` without any fields mentioned in Condition.
Can you please share what is the purpose of this condition - All records will pass trough or all records with not null values in any of the column will flow after it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All records will pass through irrespective of data values.

Regarding purpose, I am not 100% sure, but this is used as a placeholder(may be used in future), or initially there was a filter but later it was removed and filter was decommissioned and instead of removing the transformation(which needs reconnecting all ports), developer just decided to let all row pass.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of TRUE filter is often to use test different filtering conditions by overriding this property on session level. So - just as Koushik mentioned - a placeholder is created, and then developer can create one or multiple sessions where different filtering conditions may be put. Without the need to modify the mapping.